# How to make path not overwrite parent path from express

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, routes, tanstack

When the site is visited you are sent to /admin witch is right, but the content for /admin's index page does not show.

[image of the start path being /admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ol2Ev.png)

When I then click on the FAQ page the path should be /admin/FAQ but it is replaced with /FAQ.

[path of /FAQ and not /admin/FAQ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjD2k.png)

Then when the home page is clicked the content is shown but it looks like it is on / and not the index of /admin.

[the homepage shown on / and not /admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpiz3.png)

How do I make it so that everything is under /admin and doesn't overwrite that part of the path.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.